# How do I resubnet my network

Tags: dhcp

Our DHCP is running out of addresses. 
I cannot extend the range and would like to resubnet.

Right now our addresses are:

10.1.24.1-254
255.255.255.0

Would I change the subnet to 255.255.254.0 ?

What would the available addresses be at that point? 10.1.24.1 - 10.1.25.254?

Comment: Well if you add one port bit to the host address, you go from (2^8-2) to (2^9-2) available addresses (510).  10.1.24.0/23 is a valid network address.

Comment: You say you can't extend the range, but then your question is extending the range...?

Comment: I did the re subnet and should have 10.1.24.1-10.1.25.254 however, anything with 10.1.25 will not connect to the internet. Only the original 10.1.24.x address will connect. I've changed all the routers and gateways to have the 255.255.254.0 subnet and I can connect to any computer with 24 or 25 in the address. Just can 25 to connect to internet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The range of available addresses is going to be 10.1.24.1 - 10.1.25.254

If you execute `ipcalc` on linux the output is

```
# ipcalc 10.1.24.0 255.255.254.0
Address:   10.1.24.0            00001010.00000001.0001100 0.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.254.0 = 23   11111111.11111111.1111111 0.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.1.255            00000000.00000000.0000000 1.11111111
=>
Network:   10.1.24.0/23         00001010.00000001.0001100 0.00000000
HostMin:   10.1.24.1            00001010.00000001.0001100 0.00000001
HostMax:   10.1.25.254          00001010.00000001.0001100 1.11111110
Broadcast: 10.1.25.255          00001010.00000001.0001100 1.11111111
Hosts/Net: 510                   Class A, Private Internet
```

Comment: Upvote for `ipcalc`. Didn't know that existed. Nifty.

Comment: It is a good tool to calculate subnetting ranges and this type of stuff... ;)

Comment: Only problem with `ipcalc` is...based on the OP's other questions, they are in a Windows environment. :)  But the resulting output is the important thing here, not the tool used.

Comment: @TheCleaner - it's perl, so theoretically it [shouldn't be all that difficult](http://jodies.de/ipcalc-faq/win32.html) to get it running under windows.

Comment: There are a bazillion tools for this, but I'm partial to this one for Windows: http://www.bitcricket.com/ip-subnet-calculator.html

Comment: True, or just use: http://www.ijack.net/subnet.html or an online CIDR tool, etc.  Just pointing out that the answer _could_ be tailored for the OP's environment if the OP bothered to help us out up front.